# not supported or damaged pdf/doc file when downloading in php

Tags: php, download

I am downloading PDF/DOC files using php

This is my html code :

```
<a title="Download" target="_new" href="includes/pdf_server.php?file=test.pdf">Test PDF</a>
```

This is my php code in pdf_server.php file

```
<?php
$file = $_GET["file"];
if (file_exists("../PDF/".$file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode(basename($file)));
    // header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("../PDF/".$file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

**PDF** is the folder where I have my **test.pdf** file . When I click on link to download file. Browser shows file to download with its size (1.4 mb) but when download finished and I open the file it shows error either file damaged or not supported file. Then I check it's properties it shows 0 bytes.

Please help

Comment: application/force-download does not seem to be a standard mime type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this-

```
<?php
$file_name = $_GET["file"];
if (file_exists("../PDF/".$file_name)) {
    header('Pragma: public');   // required
    header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ("../PDF/".$file_name)).' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.'application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename("../PDF/".$file_name).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));    // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile("../PDF/".$file_name);     // push it out
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey its working now I changed your code at some places ("../PDF/".$file at all the places instead of $file ) now its working fine. thanks

Comment: I tried many solutions, all of them gave the same error, but yours is the most complete one, it works and also can be used inside a Controller. Thank you.

Comment: This answer could probably be improved by explaining how/why it solves the problem.